# QML ListView using QList<QObject*> as a model

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Qt's documentation seems a bit short on the issue, but I'm trying to use QLists as models for a ListView.
The thing is, I'm representing a hierarchy, and whenever an item is clicked, the model is swapped with another one, which QML gets from a C++ callback.

This is the object representing a list item:

```
class MyObject : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
  Q_PROPERTY(QString         name     READ getName WRITE setName)
  Q_PROPERTY(QString         subtitle READ getSubtitle)
  Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject*> descent  READ getChildren NOTIFY childrenUpdated)
  ...
}
```

And how I use it in QML:

```
ListView {
  id: list_view
  model: myModel
  anchors.fill: parent
  delegate: Item {
    id: row
    height: 50
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right

    MouseArea {
      anchors.fill: row
      onClicked: {
        list_view.model = descent;
      }
    }

    Column {
      Text { text: name }
      Text { text: subtitle }
    }
  }
}
```

The "myModel" model is set in the main, like this:

```
context->setContextProperty("myModel", QVariant::fromValue(folder.getChildren()));
```

The first time ListView appears, it uses myModel as a model, and it works.
Whenever I click on an item, however, the ListView creates the exact number of items expected... but it cannot read any of their properties !

How come ListView knows exactly how much items it needs to create, yet cannot see their properties ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is the correct behaviour you're observing. QML knows the number of elements in the `QList` but as far as querying them for `name` and `subtitle` that's not possible because `descent` doesn't conform to the constraints of `ListView::model`

From the QML documentation for the [ListView::model property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#model-prop):

> The model provides the set of data that is used to create the items in
>   the view. Models can be created directly in QML using ListModel,
>   XmlListModel or VisualItemModel, or provided by C++ model classes. If
>   a C++ model class is used, it must be a subclass of QAbstractItemModel
>   or a simple list.

So in that regard, you'll either have to change `descent` to be a simple list which I believe means containing simple data such as a single `QString`, `int`, etc... or implement it as `QAbstractItemModel` which contains your list of `QObjects`.

Comment: I heard about the QAbstractItemModel and was trying not to have to do that: since I'm working with simple data (QString only), I'll look into 'decent'! Thanks!